# Pandas crosstab on CategoricalDType columns throws TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, categories, crosstab

Consider this simple data set whose columns are cut by quantiles.

```
kyle = pd.DataFrame({'foo':np.random.randint(0,100,100),'boo':np.random.randint(0,100,100)})
kyle.loc[:,'fooCut'] = pd.qcut(kyle.loc[:,'foo'], np.arange(0,1.1,.1))
kyle.loc[:,'booCut'] = pd.qcut(kyle.loc[:,'boo'], np.arange(0,1.1,.1))
```

Previous versions of `Pandas` handled the below as expected...

```
pd.crosstab(kyle.fooCut,kyle.booCut)
```

After updating to version '0.24.2', the above is throwing me a `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'`

Does anyone know why and how to solve this? **Note** that here, `kyle.boocut.dtype` returns `CategoricalDtype`, a type that is the same as in the `pd.crosstab` [documentation and example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for categorical variables.

## [Update]

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25814) in pandas and is being fixed

Comment: What's your aggfunc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [uncovered by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56571306/4909087), this is an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25814) relating to pivoting (`crosstab` is an optimised version of `pivot_table` under the hood) Interval columns and is currently being fixed for v0.25.

Here's a workaround involving crosstabulating the integer codes:

```
cstab = pd.crosstab(kyle.fooCut.cat.codes, kyle.booCut.cat.codes)
cstab


col_0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
row_0                              
0      0  2  0  1  3  1  2  1  1  1
1      1  1  0  1  1  2  1  0  1  2
2      2  1  1  0  1  1  2  0  0  0
3      2  1  3  1  2  0  0  0  0  1
4      1  2  1  0  0  2  0  1  1  2
5      0  2  0  1  0  1  0  3  3  0
6      2  0  1  2  0  2  1  1  1  1
7      1  0  0  2  2  0  1  1  2  0
8      0  1  1  0  1  1  3  1  1  1
9      1  1  2  2  0  0  2  1  0  1
```

If you want to, you can always assign the index and columns of the result to the actual categories:

```
cstab.index = kyle.fooCut.cat.categories
cstab.columns = kyle.booCut.cat.categories
```

Comment: That's interesting, so even though according to `kyle.fooCut.dtype`, `footCut` is `CategoricalDtype` it isn't quite treated as such? Seems like a head scratcher

Comment: @GeneBurinsky I said the reason is possibly due to a change in the implementation, but that does not mean it is expected behaviour. It could very well be a bug. Would need to do some digging. Thankfully, the workaround is obvious and not as hack-ish as it could've been.