# Using pandas pivot_table with Interval columns results in TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

```
      cat1             cat2                       col_a             col_b
0    (34.0, 38.0]    (15.9, 47.0]             29               10
1    (34.0, 38.0]    (15.9, 47.0]             37               22
2    (28.0, 34.0]    (47.0, 56.0]              3               13
3    (34.0, 38.0]    (47.0, 56.0]             15                7
4    (28.0, 34.0]    (56.0, 67.0]             42               20
5    (28.0, 34.0]    (47.0, 56.0]             31               23
6    (28.0, 34.0]    (56.0, 67.0]             26               17
7    (28.0, 34.0]    (56.0, 67.0]              7                1
8    (28.0, 34.0]    (56.0, 67.0]             36               19
9    (19.0, 28.0]    (56.0, 67.0]              5                7
10   (19.0, 28.0]    (56.0, 67.0]             21                5
11   (28.0, 34.0]    (67.0, 84.0]             37               13
```

In the dataframe above, I want to do this pivot table operation using pandas

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='cat1', columns='cat2', values='col_a')
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Both `col_a` and `col_b` are of type int32, and `cat1` and `cat2` are of type categorical. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Not sure what Im looking at. Are your columns `cat1` and `cat2` of type string? Because they are delimited by  `(` and `]`, so they are not tuples or lists.

Comment: If you can, you could convert everything to `string` and after the `pivot_table`, re-convert to `int`. Probably not the best solution, but can't reproduce your error

Comment: Could you provide definition of your DataFrame, or csv?

Comment: What would your expected pivoted output look like? Because 'cat1' and 'cat2' are not unique - and you haven't specified any aggregation function to perform on 'col_a'

Comment: Given you have not specified an aggfunc, the default is assumed to be "mean".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug related to pivoting columns that are intervals (see [GH25814](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25814)) and will be fixed for v0.25. 
Also see this related question using `crosstab`: [Pandas crosstab on CategoricalDType columns throws TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571306/pandas-crosstab-on-categoricaldtype-columns-throws-typeerror/56571354?r=SearchResults&s=3|45.6303#56571354)

Here are some options in the meantime. To aggregate, you will have to use `pivot_table` and convert your categorical cols to string before pivoting.

```
df2 = df.assign(cat1=df['cat1'].astype(str), cat2=df['cat2'].astype(str))
# to aggregate by taking the mean of col_a
df2.pivot_table(index='cat1', columns='cat2', values='col_a', aggfunc='mean')
```

The caveat here is that you lose the benefit of your index and columns being intervals.

Another option would be to pivot on the categorical codes, then reassign the categories:

```
df2 = df.assign(cat1=df['cat1'].cat.codes, cat2=df['cat2'].cat.codes)
pivot = df2.pivot_table(
    index='cat1', columns='cat2', values='col_a', aggfunc='mean')

pivot.index = df['cat1'].cat.categories
pivot.columns = df['cat2'].cat.categories
```

This assignment will work because `pivot_table` sorts the intervals before-hand.

---

**Minimal Code Sample**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat1': np.random.choice(100, 10), 
    'cat2': np.random.choice(100, 10), 
    'col_a': np.random.randint(1, 50, 10)})

df['cat1'] = pd.cut(df['cat1'], bins=np.arange(0, 101, 10))
df['cat2'] = pd.cut(df['cat2'], bins=np.arange(0, 101, 10))

df
          A         B   C
0  (40, 50]  (60, 70]  18
1  (40, 50]  (80, 90]  38
2  (60, 70]  (80, 90]  26
3  (60, 70]  (10, 20]  14
4  (60, 70]  (50, 60]   9
5   (0, 10]  (60, 70]  10
6  (80, 90]  (30, 40]  21
7  (20, 30]  (80, 90]  17
8  (30, 40]  (40, 50]   6
9  (80, 90]  (80, 90]  16
```

```
(df.assign(cat1=df['cat1'].astype(str), cat2=df['cat2'].astype(str))
   .pivot_table(index='cat1', columns='cat2', values='col_a', aggfunc='mean'))

cat2      (10, 20]  (30, 40]  (40, 50]  (50, 60]  (60, 70]  (80, 90]
cat1                                                                
(0, 10]        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      10.0       NaN
(20, 30]       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      17.0
(30, 40]       NaN       NaN       6.0       NaN       NaN       NaN
(40, 50]       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      18.0      38.0
(60, 70]      14.0       NaN       NaN       9.0       NaN      26.0
(80, 90]       NaN      21.0       NaN       NaN       NaN      16.0
```